# How to get absolute url to javascript asset pack with webpacker gem, Rails 5.1 rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I need to get the absolute url a javascript pack and I'm having trouble finding a method in which to do it in the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be working for me

`<%= url_to_asset(Webpacker::Manifest.lookup("app.js")) %>`

Comment: that outputs a relative url, the question is asking for absolute url

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me by using this :

`<%= asset_pack_path('scripts.js') %>`

For more info check this [link](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/5-x-stable/docs/assets.md)

Comment: this answer is correct and it should be the correct answer! it's weird that it was down-voted (-1) :/ :/ there are terrible people in this world, I'm up-voting it +1

Comment: Works perfectly with Rails 6. Do not forget the `.js` file extension (whereas `javascript_pack_tag` does not need it).